# How do you link an eclipse project to an eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am building an eclipse plug-in project that acts as a front end. I also have a separate eclipse project that runs as a backend. Right now I can run each of them separately and they communicate just fine using sockets.

I would like the plug-in to create the major components of the back end when it starts but also keep the two projects separate so that I can use other editors to communicate with the back end. So, I added the back end eclipse project to the build properties of the plug-in project and I added some code from the back end driver to the plug-in activator's start(). However, when I run the plug-in project I am getting class not found exceptions for all back end references. It appears to compile fine, but I can't run it. I do not do anything to the MANIFEST.MF file in the plug-in project.

How does one add a second java project to an eclipse plug-in project?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this, going from best and most difficult to worst and easiest:

(1) Use a build tool (such as the built-in ANT, or tycho, or (as I'm sure there are) some other). This is by far the best solution, but is quite a bit more involved than the next 2.

(2) Convert your non-plugin project to a plugin project and add it as a plugin dependency in your plugin settings file's dependencies tab

(3) Export your non-plugin to a new .jar in your plugin project directory (e.g. `$project_loc/lib/something.jar`); go into plugin settings (plugin.xml) and include it in: The `Build` tab under `binary build`, and the `Runtime` tab under `Classpath`. (Or edit the corresponding entries in `manifest.mf` and `build.properties`)

For most cases I'd recommend approach (1); look up a few tutorials online, there are plenty. (3) is the quick-and-dirty non-flexible workaround to your particular situation, good for nothing other than seeing if it actually can run. (2) is somewhere in between -- obviously not ideal, but not as bad as 3.

Comment: I'm curious about your thoughts on why option 3 is so bad. What are the pitfalls of doing the easiest thing possible?

Comment: @MarkM It's not flexible or scalable -> you'd have to redo it for any small change, and you'd have to shuffle around potentially massive archives, while manually keeping track of any dependencies. That's quite enough to make both debugging and maintenance hell :-)